# Finding birth/baptism record for James Chichester who died 1858 in British Guiana?

Tags: 19th-century, england, baptism-records, guyana

James Chichester was my great-great grandfather.

James Chichester was a native of Europe and an inhabitant of the County of East Demerara, British Guiana. James lived in Mahaecony, East Coast Demerara. (These details are written in his will.)

James died November 23, 1858, in Georgetown, British Guiana, and is listed on the [British Guiana Colonists Index "C"](http://www.vc.id.au/tb/bgcolonistsC.html)

James was one of two brothers who migrated from Europe. It is believed his brother’s name was Edward Chichester.

James fathered eight children with Betsy Anne Joe, namely Charles James; Henry; Thomas; Agnis Giles (nee Chichester); Henry Edward; William; James; and John.

George S. Chichester signed as witness to the will of James' son Charles James Chichester.

How could I try to find his birth and/or baptism record(s)?

I do not have any ship records for him travelling to/from British Guiana.

I have located the listing of the probated will of James Chichester from both Guyana records and the [England & Wales National Probate Calendar](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=1904).  His brother Edward was listed as executor and swore oath to the authentication. I am enclosing a copy of the UK listing.

[image: James Chichester, National Probate Calendar, 1860]

From the England and Wales, National Probate Calendar Index of Wills and Administration 1858-1966 I obtiained the second listing of James Chichester's Will.  Here is a copy:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  I encourage all new users of Stack Exchange to read the information in the [help], especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack Exchange is a question-and-answer site, intended for helping people solve specific problems.  I am putting your post on hold until it is edited and improved because it is not a question, and does not fit our format.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE.  I would love to see some questions and answers (in our focussed Q&A format) from you regarding the Chichesters about who you clearly have much knowledge.  My 3rd great grandmother Priscilla Chichester and my 4th great grandfather Robert Chichester both had brothers in British Guyana during the 1820s-1830s but I am not able to say whether they are or are not closely related to your ancestors (I suspect not but ...).  You can find previous Q&As here about those Chichesters by clicking http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/search?q=chichester

Comment: The question that I would be keen to see you ask, which you could do by using the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it, is: "Where to find birth/baptism records for James Chichester (d.1858, British Guiana) and his brother Charles?"  Of the six Chichesters listed on the [British Guiana Colonists Index "C"](http://www.vc.id.au/tb/bgcolonistsC.html) I can identify four but not James (or Robert).

Comment: Many thanks for editing your question, and I hope you do not mind that I edited it a little more to: (1) make the title a summary of the question; (2) focus on finding the birth/baptism record a little more (ship records could come out in that process or be asked about separately later); and (3) remove the "any other information" and where to find your tree information because while that is interesting our potential answerers will look at the question and source records rather than on people's trees.

Comment: Would you be able to [edit] into your question a timeline to summarize what you know of James in British Guiana prior to his death, please?  I'm interested in trying to determine when he first arrived.  Without a shipping record (and to perhaps help find a shipping record) perhaps things like the years his children were born and whether he was named on their baptism records or just named them as his children on his will.  Do you know how old he was when he died?

Comment: Thanks for editing... I'll ask a few other family members and see how much more I can find out, based on your input.

Comment: I think any evidence that you may have linking James to a brother named William or George will also be valuable.  I think evidence supports that the William Chichester listed on the [British Guiana Colonists Index "C"](http://www.vc.id.au/tb/bgcolonistsC.html) is a brother to my 4th great grandfather Robert.  I have no evidence that Robert himself was ever in British Guiana but his two sons (Jared and Thomas; both listed; nephews to William) were.  As far as I know Robert did not have a brother named James.

Comment: The only thing I have is that a George S. Chichester signed as witness to the will of Charles J. Chichester...

Comment: We should edit this into your question too. I gather that Charles J. who you also have a will for is Charles James the son of James (d.1858). I think being a witness may only suggest/indicate that Charles has a relative named George S.

Comment: I agree... However, I am are checking other sets of documents... also, will be calling some relatives in Guyana... will advise...

Comment: It seems likely that "James Chichester was a native of Europe" but is there any source that says this explicitly?

Comment: I quoted from his will, which began, "In the name of God. Amen. I James Chichester a native of Europe and inhabitant of the County of Demerara in the Colony of British Guiana being of sound mind memory and understanding..."

Comment: I am keen to know where in Guyana you found a listing of James Chichester's probated will?  I would like to try and use the same source to see if there is any information on other Chichesters there e.g. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/where-to-find-will-of-giles-chichester-from-1820s-probably-in-somerset-or-guyan

Comment: Did you find the information you were looking for? I think I have the information you are seeking, including james' confirmed ancestors going back to 1620 but it may be that you now have it all? Please let me know if you wish me to send to you what I have

Comment: Hi, Karen, welcome to G&FH.SE!  I'm converting your post to a comment because it is not an answer.  If you'd like more information about the site works, you can take the [tour], explore the [help], and read our companion [Meta] area.

Comment: Hi Karen, hopefully we can communicate through this avenue. I am still researching as much details of the Chichesters I can get my hands on. Your information would be welcome. Thanks.  Valerie Lauzon

Answer (score 2):

From the England, Wales National Probate 1858 - 1966 probate record that you added to your question, I searched FindMyPast for an Edward Chichester born within 10 years of 1810 (as a bit of a guess) and came up with an 1861 Census Record for Edward Chichester at Cradley which said that he was born in Somerset.  This greatly interested me because my Chichester ancestors come from Old Cleeve in Somerset.

I then switched over to Ancestry.com and searched for an Edward Chichester born within 5 years of 1808 and found one baptised on 2 Nov 1806 to Giles and Ann.  That census record only gave the location as being Somerset, but I recognized the names from the [OLD CLEEVE BAPTISMS 1784 TO 1812](http://www.wsom.org.uk/Registers/OClevBap17841812.htm) which record the same details.

Giles Chichester who married Ann Stenner on 10 Jun 1798 at Old Cleeve (see [OLD CLEEVE MARRIAGES 1754 TO 1812](http://www.wsom.org.uk/Registers/OClevMar17541812.htm)) was a brother to my 4th great grandfather Robert Chichester who has been [mentioned in several of my questions here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/search?q=robert%20chichester).

The next thing was to find Edward's brother James (your 2nd great grandfather) which was easy via my Ancestry.com tree.  Edward had two brothers named James:

- the first was baptised on 18 Sep 1808 to Giles and Ann (see [OLD CLEEVE BAPTISMS 1784 TO 1812](http://www.wsom.org.uk/Registers/OClevBap17841812.htm)) and buried on 8 Jan 1815 (see [OLD CLEEVE BURIALS 1813 TO 1831](http://www.wsom.org.uk/Registers/OClevBur18131831.htm))
- the second was baptised on 20 Feb 1820 to Giles and Ann (see [OLD CLEEVE BAPTISMS 1813 TO 1830](http://OLD%20CLEEVE%20BAPTISMS%201813%20TO%201830)) and he seems to be your 2nd great grandfather James Chichester.

---

As a footnote,  Giles' brother, uncle to your James, was [William Chichester](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/lbs/person/view/45306) and I already knew that two of William's other nephews (Jared and Thomas, and possibly their only other brother Giles; all sons of Robert) were with him at Demerara.  However, I did not know that another nephew went there too.

Also, we were lucky to find Edward at Cradley because he lived abroad for many years, marrying Ann Maria (no surname given but baptism records of their children upon return to England show that it was Spicer) at Launceston, Tasmania, Australia on 25 Jun 1838 and having eight children there between 1839 and 1854 before having his last one born at Gloucester, Gloucestershire in 1855.

Comment: Is any of this relevent, or have you seen/deciphered this? 

https://archive.org/stream/historyoffamilyo00chic#page/n123/mode/2up

Valerie

Comment: @OsvenaLauzon I'm aware of that book, but as yet I have not determined where our Chichesters might fit in it.  If they do, I suspect it will be around p.227 of 396 where it talks about a John Chichester (1664-1699) who had sons Giles and Robert and other children with connections to Old Cleeve and Leighland.  Those names and locations feature prominently in our Chichester ancestry about 75-100 years later.